# Is it possible to find an expression for the x-value of where the normal line to a function hits another function? (Picture shown)

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

[image: Visual of the problem]

I was dabbling in some recreational math and I stumbled upon this problem:

Say there are two arbitrary functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. Create the normal line to $g(x)$ at $x_g$; now find an expression for $x_f$, the x-value of where the normal line hits $f(x)$, in terms of $x_g$. So essentially, find $x_f(x_g)$.

The equation of the normal line is simple to find: $y=\frac{-1}{g'(x_g)}(x-x_g)+g(x_g)$

My main method for trying to solve this problem has been with geometric constructions involving the angles shown and lengths of the triangles shown. The zero of the normal line is $x=g(x_g)g'(x_g)+x_g$ and the zero of the tangent line is $x=x_g-\frac{g(x_g)}{g'(x_g)}$. Given these lengths and others in the diagram, I have not been able to solve the problem by finding some proportion or geometric expression relating $x_f$ to $x_g$.

My question is if such an expression is even possible to create and if so, how would it be done? I apologize for not having more information on the problem and how it could be solved, this is all I've gotten after hours of working this problem. Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You claim:

> The equation of the normal line is simple to find: $y=\frac{-1}{g'(x_g)}(x-x_g)+g(x_g)$

Let the right-hand side of your equation be $h(x)$. Then, assuming it is correct, you can then find the [abscissa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abscissa) of the point of intersection of the line given by $y=h(x)$ with the [locus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locus_(mathematics)) of points $(x,y)$ determined by $y=f(x)$ by [solving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_solving) the following [system of equations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SystemofEquations.html) for $x$:
\begin{cases}
y=h(x);\\
y=f(x).
\end{cases}
Please comment if you want me to elaborate further.

Comment: Solving that system of equations would give $x_g-g'(x_g) (f(x_f) - g(x_g)) =x_f$ which contains that pesky $f(x_f)$, so it's not an expression for $x_f$ in terms of $x_g$

Comment: @B.Sandoval your solution for $x$ does not start with $x=\dotsc$

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't start with "x=..."?

Comment: $x_f$ is the x-value that will satisfy both equations, so the solution for x will be $x_f$ as shown

Comment: @B.Sandoval oh I see, so you tell me $x=x_f$. But hey, you didn't solve your last $x_g-g'(x_g) (f(x_f) - g(x_g))=x_f$ one for $x_f$ then. That's exactly why it is not an expression for $x$ in other terms. Although you can check whether or not the expression is correct by substitution of some exact $f$.

Comment: Well that would mean that the expression would depend on $f(x)$. My question is if there is a general expression for finding $x_f(x_g)$ for ANY set of functions.

Comment: @B.Sandoval you basically want to solve $kx+f(x)=0$ for $x$. Can you continue from that?

Comment: I'm sorry for the extended questioning, but could you explain how you arrived at the equation above? I appreciate your help

Comment: @B.Sandoval no problem. Actually, the correct form is $kx+f(x)=c$ instead, because notice that your long equation you give in your second comment to my answer actually has that form for some $k$ and $c$, as the terms $g'(x_g)$, $x_g$ etc are independent of $x_f$.